# Find a specific string in a directory then copy files containing that string to a new directory

Tags: bash, terminal, data-cleaning

I am an absolute beginner and would appreciate any help. I am cleaning data to work with in R and I want to chose some files that meet specific parameters and put them together in a director

This is the what I am putting into commandline I have a couple of issues:

```bash
grep -l -r "r" ~Documents/Splicing/revs_POSTr/*.txt | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' ~/Documents/Splicing/Misspliced
```

1. When I input this I keep getting the same error

   > grep: ~Documents/Splicing/revs_PRE/*.txt: No such file or directory

   but the directory and files definitely do exist
   [picture of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jkoM.png)

2. The string I am looking for is not actually just "r" each .txt file contains a list with each entry LRR12r or LRR12 etc I want to only return files when the lowercase "r" appears after a number as sometimes there are entries that say Postr and I don't want those.

Comment: You mean `~/Documents` `Documents` directory in the current user's home directory, but you have `~Documents` which is home directory of the user `Documents`. So add the `/`

Comment: Fabulous! thanks so much that fixed problem 1.

Answer (score 1):

So you want any digit before the `r`, then use

```
grep -l '[[:digit:]]r' ~/Documents/Splicing/revs_POSTr/*.txt | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' ~/Documents/Splicing/Misspliced
```

you don't need `-r` as you are not going into directories.